# Converting Long/Lat into X/Y in the same coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, fme-form

I have a text file with two fields including Longitude and Latitude in degrees. I need to convert this into two fields that contain these values in X and Y. The source and destination coordinate system have to be the same: ESPG: 4236 - WGS 84.

I have tried the AttributeReprojector but it does not seem to work and the new X Attribute and Y attributes seem to be the same values as the original Longitude and Latitude.

Does anyone have an idea of how this could be resolved in FME?

I am showing a sample of the data below:
[image]

What I basically need is to get the X and Y corresponding to the Long/Lat in the projection WGS 84.

Comment: please give a example two fields then can create points for the reprojector transformer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot have it in the same coordinate system because EPSG 4326 is a degree system. What you sould do instead to transform it to EPSG 3857 which is wgs84 world mercator.
See the link: http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/6864/

Comment: Just to clarify, EPSG:3857 is WGS84 **Web Mercator** -- EPSG:3395 is WGS84 **World Mercator**. Similar, but not quite the same projection.

Comment: My mistake, you are right. It's web mercator. But also a world coordinate system.

Comment: I understand what you mean. So I will have to re-project in other coordinate system in order to get proper X and Y coordinates. I will have a go!

Comment: How did you progress with the reprojection? Is that worked?